# How to design and implement schedulable alarms/events which trigger parts of code in C

Tags: c, events, calendar, scheduling

I have a piece of code which acts as a server and is switching different valves and other actuators. The commands for switching those actuators are being received via sockets from clients running on Android devices. Now Id like to add a module to my server which would allow me to schedule an calendar dependant switching of those actuators. I wonder how to do that. 
Right now I am thinking of time.h of course, as the very basic. Then I could imagine to have a stucture which holds the programmable events (time, date and what to trigger) and a task which would endlessly compare the time/date to the actual time.. However I am not really sure if that is the right approach. Please hint me in the right direction.

1. What would the basic architecture look like?
2. Are there libraries in C I could youse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options include:

- setitimer() to set next signal time, and using a signal handler.
- having a loop, sleeping, polling and checking system time against time for the schedule.

Comment: Considering a loop, (comparing the scheduled time/date to the actual time/date) wouldn`t it waste processor time?

Comment: What type resolution do you need?  If only once a min then sleep every 10sec and you will have next to 0 CPU usage for code.

Comment: user3431837 Yes, I thought of 1 min Resolution.Indeed you are right, to check for example 20 structures it would only take fractions of milliseconds or even less. I think I'll start implementing..